# Access violation when calling ClearDepthStencilView in DX12

Tags: depth-buffer, directx-12

I'm trying to learn DirectX12 and have been following along with [3dgep's tutorial](https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-2/).

When I attempt to clear the depth stencil view, it works fine on the first call but throws

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA81B8D62C (nvwgf2umx.dll) in ARTG.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000008C.

on subsequent calls.

I currently clear the depth stencil like so:

```cpp
// get a fresh command list, which will've been automatically reset
ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList2> commandList = m_directCommandQueue->GetCommandList();

D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE dsv = m_DSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
commandList->ClearDepthStencilView(dsv, D3D12_CLEAR_FLAG_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0, 0, nullptr);
```

I use the same command list for clearing the render target view on the previous line. `m_DSVHeap` is a `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12DescriptorHeap>`, and is created as follows:

```cpp
// create descriptor heap for depth-stencil view
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC dsvHeapDesc = {};
dsvHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = 1; // only the depth stencil view needs to be on the heap
dsvHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_DSV;  // DSV descriptor heap
dsvHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;    // shader flags do not apply to DSV heaps as shaders do not reference them
ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&dsvHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_DSVHeap)));  // create descriptor heap from descriptor
```

I'm mostly trying to find out if there's an essential step I've missed, I don't understand why it doesn't throw an exception on the first frame.

Comment: Are you possibly calling &m_DSVHeap somewhere else where you are not creating it? Do you use debug layer?

Comment: @mateeeeeee m_DSVHeap is only touched when I:  
- Create it.  
- Resize the window (which doesn't happen).  
- Clear it in render.  

I have the debug layer and GPU validation enabled but I'm unfamiliar with how I would use them to solve this problem.  

Thank you very much, I hope you're having a great day.

Comment: Debug layer would log errors if they catch it in your Output window. Could you provide your gfx code somewhere like in pastebin or github, or even better minimal reproducable example somewhere? It's very hard to guess since the problem could be caused by tons of things.

Comment: @mateeeeeee it's alright, I'm gonna try compare it to some of the samples and see if I can spot what's going wrong. thanks for all the help

Comment: When debugging, check before your 2nd call to clear depth if m_DSVHeap is nullptr, the address accessed 0x000000000000008C suggests that. I think this might be the issue: m_DSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

Comment: @mateeeeeee it ended up being a symptom of a larger issue to do with how I was resetting command lists. Thank you for all your help.